# How to remove 'fake' employees of a company in LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

How can I remove 'fake' employees of a company in LinkedIn?

There are multiple fake employees who say they work for a company LinkedIn page I am managing, but they do not, nor never have. How can I remove them?

Comment: the thing is you cant. they can lie about it same as you do and vice versa. the point is that LinkedIn doesn't care who lies so at the end of the day the truth is lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try filing a "[Notice of Inaccurate Profile Information](https://linkedin.com/help/linkedin/ask/TS-NFPI)"

From [LinkedIn help](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1589/removing-people-from-a-company-or-university-page?lang=en):

> Since members provide this data, it's not possible for an administrator to remove employees from a Company Page or University Page.
>
> If you'd like us to investigate further, you can file a formal complaint using the Notice of Inaccurate Profile Information. We'll review your request and respond as soon as possible.